# Required Chromedriver version with Webdrivers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Since I updated Chrome, my tests don't work anymore.
I get this error:

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76`

So I replaced

```
# Currently I have Chrome 78 installed
Webdrivers::Chromedriver.required_version = Webdrivers::Chromedriver.current_version.to_s
```

by

```
Webdrivers::Chromedriver.required_version = '76.0.3809.68'
```

But I got the exactly same error.
I also tried with the `76.0.3869.25`.

As you can see here: https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/blob/master/lib/webdrivers/chromedriver.rb#L76

The required version exists.

My tests are working on Travis. Any idea?

Comment: From what I've seen webdrivers chromedriver requires the same version of chrome as it's installed on your computer. Have you tried downgrading chrome or updating chromedriver version to the same as your chrome version?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lavilet, I guess that should works if I downgrade to the 76 version, but I try to find a solution to keep Chrome up to date and to run correctly the tests. It seems like there's no a good management of the chrome versions... Maybe if I download the Chrome Dev or Beta with the required version. Anyway, the code mention below should works because the version is available on the Google's repo. :/

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem today, and was able to fix it....

System: Windows10 Enterprise Desktop, Visual Studio Pro 2017

1. Used the VS Nuget UI to update the Selenium.WebDriver.Chrome package
2. Normally, this works, but I **continued to get the same error** as above

To fix:
- I went to where my Chromedriver.exe file was located **and removed it**.
- Then I re-built my application that uses Selenium
- My VS app then **loaded a new Chromedriver.exe** 
3. Re-ran my Selenium test: *Problem solved*.